# Padding changes in Safari and Firefox

Tags: html, css, browser, padding, nav

I have this nav, and it looks amazing in Chrome!  The only problem is that in Safari, and Firefox the padding renders differently and the nav items are visible outside of the header.  This problem could be fixed with `overflow:hidden;` but I can't add that due to the green logo.  Any suggestions?  I thought doing this method with widths and heights would fix it, but I can't change the width and/or heights of the lis.

JS fiddle :: http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewKosloski/2MX94/

Comment: This jsFiddle works for me (Firefox 22), try to reset your CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added line-height: 1.2 like this:

```
nav li a {
color: #fff;
padding: 50px 85px;
line-height: 1.2;
}
```

and that seems to worked on both chrome and safari